# Swipe Gesture on whole RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement swipe gesture on whole RecyclerView to show/hide thumbnails. Please see below image.

[image]

It is working but not working smoothly. Sometimes it does if we start scrolling recyclerView it scrolls with jerks.

Please find my code below

```
....

public class ChatFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

OnSwipeInteractionListener listener;
private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private int min_distance = 100;
private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ChatFragment() {
}

public static ChatFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
    ChatFragment fragment = new ChatFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    Context context = view.getContext();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(HeaderDecoration.with(recyclerView)
            .inflate(R.layout.inflate_header_view_chat)
            .parallax(0.8f)
            .dropShadowDp(0)
            .build());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), getDummyData(), mListener, this));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    return view;
}

private ArrayList<PostItemParent> getDummyData() {
    ArrayList<PostItemParent> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        ArrayList<PostItem> postItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 1; j < 15; j++) {
            postItems.add(new PostItem("" + (j + 1), "This is the dummy post, will ne changed after enabling api", j % 3 == 0, getAttachments()));
        }
        PostItemParent postItemParent = new PostItemParent("header " + i, postItems);
        posts.add(postItemParent);
    }


    return posts;
}

private ArrayList<PostItem.AttachmentItem> getAttachments() {
    ArrayList<PostItem.AttachmentItem> attachmentItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(i % 3 == 0)
            attachmentItems.add(new PostItem.AttachmentItem(FileUtils.FILE_TYPE_IMAGE, true, false, true, "fiel url", "file url") );
        else
            attachmentItems.add(new PostItem.AttachmentItem(FileUtils.FILE_TYPE_OTHER, true, false, true, "fiel url", "file url") );
    }

    return attachmentItems;
}

public void setListener(OnSwipeInteractionListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}



@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > min_distance) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        listener.onLeftToRighSwipeDone();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        listener.onRightToLeftSwipeDone();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public interface OnSwipeInteractionListener {

    /**
     * called when LTR swipe done
     */
    void onLeftToRighSwipeDone();

    /**
     * on RTL swipe done
     */
    void onRightToLeftSwipeDone();
}


}
```

Comment: use `GestureDetector` for such purposes

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: yes @Andrea I've used 'onTouch()' to detect the swipe

Comment: can you post a snippet of your solution please, the problem is that I don't know how to make the rest of the layout visible when its swiped

Comment: You have to show/hide view in **onBindViewHolder()**.